# How to calculate GA4's "user retention" from BigQuery events

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I need to reproduce "User retention" graph (Last 42 days ending in XXX) of GA4. However I couldn't get the same result as GA4 from my guessed formulas (avg of Dx users in (42-Dx) days /D0 users in (42-Dx) days)

Have someone already calculated such metric?

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide further clarification on what you are attempting to do and what the discrepancy is?